# POSIX, pass application data between pthread_t's

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix

I'm trying to find a way to pass a custom (void*) pointer from one thread to another using pthread_kill().

The scenario is this: multiple custom async alarms are invoked from a single thread(for some blocking operations like read, listen, etc) and i want to be able, in the handler, to make a distinction between timeout signals received based on a custom attribute.

I've looked into the handler

```
void handler(int, siginfo_t*, void*)
```

used in conjuction with `SA_SIGINFO` and found the `struct sigval` but i couldn't find a way to pass some data with the help of it.

I suppose one way around would have been the 
`int sigqueue(pid_t pid, int sig, const union sigval value);` 
but i am running on OSX and it's not implemented (https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/sigqueue.html).

Thank you if you can suggest me an ideea regarding this problem.

Comment: `listen()`  blocks?

Comment: no, it doesn't; i meant accept().

Comment: Signals are not a good tool for this, or for much of anything. This sounds like an XY Problem.

Comment: ok, i understand a good 10% of your reply :)

Comment: I'd use SysV IPC to pass your values (e.g. `msgsnd` and `msgrcv`). They have much better R/T characteristics for passing data around. Trying to use a signal handler to pass data is doing it the hard way. Save it for true exceptions.

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/168083)

Comment: yes, the xy problem and the generic unusefulness of signals; my question is about filling the sigval argument but, hey, the xy paradigm may be applied to almost anything.

Comment: Craig, thanks, i'll look into it!